# Ace editor is showing the error: Line too long

Tags: python, angular, ace-editor, linter

I use ace-linters for ace editor. It is showing the relevant linter warnings for each line on the left bar.

[image]

I have this *line too long* error. but I do not need this to show. Is it possible to remove this error?

Is there any way to have more control on the rules used by ace linters for python language. I noticed that it uses ruff for python linting.
https://github.com/mkslanc/ace-linters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a custom set of rules for services in `ace-linters`. To do this for a Python service, you need to provide your own configuration to the `configuration` property. For instance, if you want to increase the line length, you can use the following snippet:

```js
languageProvider.setGlobalOptions("python", {
    configuration: {
        "line-length": 120
    }
});
```

[Full list of available options for Python Service based on Ruff](https://github.com/charliermarsh/ruff/blob/main/ruff.schema.json)

Comment: Is there a way to ignore some words? for example I have a variable "export"
It ll throw an error undefined name. but i have a list of words to ignore.
dummy-variable-rgx didnt seem to work

Comment: But i noticed that dummy-variable-rgx is to not throw unused variable error. 
I need a way to add some keywords and the linter to ignore them from undefined variables